# module_function in an IRB session?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming, irb

I've some troubles to understand why the [`Module#module_function`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-module_function) is missing in the following irb session ?

```
> class << self      # open singleton for the session's object instance
>   p is_a? Module   # true
>   p respond_to? :module_function   # false ??
> end
```

What am I trying to achieve ? Use directly an external module in an irb session, ie. without wrapping it in a new module. The external module dynamically creates method(s) with module_eval then calls module_function on the new method name.

```
> require 'dlx/normalize'  # true
> class << self
>   extend DLX::Normalize   # main
>   generic_bind 'laplace-inverse'  # calling DLX::Normalize.generic_bind
> end
NoMethodError: undefined method `module_function' for #<Class:#<Object:0x0000000092e6e0>>
```

What am I missing here ? Is accessing the the *outermost* Module class in irb with `class << self` or `singleton_class.module_exec` the right way ? Why is the `module_function` missing even if the class *is* the descendant of `Module` ?

**Update:**
To make my question even more explicit, wrapping the above code in a new module definition does work. I cann't understand why is this wrapping needed.

```
> require 'dlx/normalize'  # true
> module Dummy
>   extend DLX::Normalize   # main
>   generic_bind 'laplace-inverse'  # calling DLX::Normalize.generic_bind
>                                   # this method calls module_function
> end
> Dummy.generated_laplace(1.234)    # got new module's method
>                                   # previous call to module_function
>                                   # did succeeded
```

Comment: Could you please frame your confusion more specifically?

Comment: External module uses `Module#module_function`. After module's method added with `extend` in IRB, calls fails with *NoMethodError* where `module_function` method should not be missing. It's a standard part of `Module` definition.

Answer (score 0):

```
Module.new.respond_to? :module_function
=> false
```

Also

```
module Foo
  p respond_to? :module_function
end
=> false
```

So you 'll get the same answer in any descendent I expect.

Comment: This is very strange.  ```module Foo ; p respond_to? :module_function # false; def test; 42; end ; module_function :test ; end``` and ```include Foo; test  # 42``` So it looks like ```module_function``` is *not* a method of Module class. So what is then ?